# Accessing props state from componentDidMount method gives undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new to react and redux, I am trying to access the store from componentDidMount method, but always give me undefined, and when console the state from mapActionToState first time give me undefined and then give me the real state

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class UserProperties extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabs: {
        published: true,
        drafts: false,
        pending: false,
        rejected: false
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Add Property | Real Estate";
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
  }
}

let mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
    return state.user
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

The redux state is injected into your props, so in order to access it in your componentDidMount you need to log `this.props` instead of `this.state`. Note that `mapStateToProps` expects an `Object` where the keys correspond to the keys in your props. Which means that if your `state.user` looks like

```
{
 name: 'Name',
 role: 'administrator'
}
```

Then with your current code you will find that your props have two properties `this.props.name` and `this.props.role` respectively.

A better way of writing this would be

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
    return {user: state.user}
};
```

After which your user object can be accessed as `this.props.user`.

Comment: I fixed it as you said and still can't find it inside props
when the componentDidMount receives the props?

Comment: Oh I see..the problem here is that `componentDidMount` is only called once when the component is mounted. If you want to log the changes as your component updates try logging inside the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method.

Comment: I am want to get the current user from the store and save it to my component state, when i am trying to do this, an error occurs that the maximum depth exceeded

Comment: The point of redux is to abstract your state away to the redux lifecycle...Although it is not uncommon to use component state along with redux state management, you should generally try to avoid derivign state from your props/redux-state. Please go through the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) here to learn more about this.

Comment: The reason for your max depth exceeded is because you are trying to set state in shouldComponentUpdate, which triggers another call to shouldComponentUpdate..which is an endless recursive loop. In order to avoid this you need to conditionally call setState depending on whether or not the props changed..as described in the documentation I referenced above.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was useful, i appreciate your time sir